# rest behaviour in backbone.js

Tags: json, backbone.js, django-rest-framework

Iam confusing about apis using in backbone.js and using djangorestframework for apis,I was checked in json response that while using **GET,POST** "id" field is not included in json response,but when using **PUT** ,json shows "id" field because of this iam getting reponse as

```
"id" field doesn't exists
```

my doubt is all rests behaviour like this or only this,while [refer this](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/41),he stripped the id in backbone.sync ,is it possible.

Comment: where are you seeing this response?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.js sends all data of the model in create and update actions (POST and PUT). For create (POST), the object doesn't have an id, as the id is created on the server.

Overriding Backbone.sync is a perfectly valid approach, as stripping the id needs to be done for all PUT requests - the other would be to modify the server side to accept data in the format that backbone.js expects.